# Differences between SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I wonder if there are differences between the two versions?
10.50.2500 SQL Server 2008 R2 
10.50.1600 SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

10.50.2500.0 is actually 2008 R2 with **service pack 1**

Service Pack 1 addressed many problems in the R2 RTM - for details, refer to that service packs release notes:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2973.microsoft-sql-server-2008-r2-sp1-release-notes.aspx

and

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2463333

Answer (score 10):

Definitions for different version of SQL server is as

- CTP means Community Technology Preview. It means you can use it but
  its not the final version of a software and things  may change when
  product is finally released.
- RTM means release to manufacturing.
- SPs are service packs. It means product updates and bug fixes for
  that release.
- While R2 referes to  Release 2, and it generally includes
  enhancements that can not be included as part of service packs.
  You can read more [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlgetstarted/thread/d83c426a-9b15-48e0-a99f-f14f8d4f8818)
  In order to determine the current version you can see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185)

Answer (score 1):

10.50.2500 SQL Server 2008 R2 -This is Sql Server 2008 with service pack 1

Here 10.50 represents the version number and 2500 represents Sql serevr Service pack levels.

10.50.1600 SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM-This is sql server R2 RTM means Release to Manufacturer means Customers can use this version using licences final release after the beta versions.

Every three months microsoft releases the service packs.